# What is the recommended architecture when using AWS Cognito Signup in a mobile app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to use AWS Cognito for authentication in my mobile app.

Currently my app's backend stores all user details in a User table in MySQL and has relationships to other tables (say with Orders table etc). When I user Cognito Signup, do I have to first signup the user with cognito and then again pass on these details to my backend, so that it can store details in my User table?

How would we handle a case where cognito signup goes through correctly but it fails when I pass on the details to my app's backend (say because my server was down)?

What is the recommended architecture here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I user Cognito Signup, do I have to first signup the user with
>   Cognito and then again pass on these details to my backend, so that it
>   can store details in my User table?

Yes, it will be useful also to save the user details in a user table. This will be used when querying the database for the application features.

> How would we handle a case where Cognito signup goes through correctly
>   but it fails when I pass on the details to my app's backend (say
>   because my server was down)?

Do this in a fault tolerant manner, using [Lambda triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html) from Cognito before user signed up (pre-signup), Lambda function will include the code to update the database and if it successful, Cognito will proceed with the sign-up.

Answer (score 1):

> When I user Cognito Signup, do I have to first signup the user with cognito and then again pass on these details to my backend, so that it can store details in my User table?

AWS Congnito provides options to invoke Lambda functions on certain Cognito events, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html

In the UserPool trigger you can define a "Pre-sign up" lambda which will be invoked when a user submits their information to sign up

> How would we handle a case where cognito signup goes through correctly but it fails when I pass on the details to my app's backend (say because my server was down)?

According to the documentation:

`Amazon Cognito invokes Lambda functions synchronously. When called, your Lambda function must respond within 5 seconds. If it does not, Amazon Cognito retries the call. After 3 unsuccessful attempts, the function times out. This 5-second timeout value cannot be changed`

There are several options:

- If you need to be fault tolerant, you can use SQS for ensure reliable delivery. In this case you will need to read and process the queue
- you can implements your own error handling (e.g. store, retry, send a mail, etc ..)